# How to change the text colour of a materialize input field within local home.scss file

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

Framework: react on rails
CSS: Materialize

So I'm using materialize's defualt css package and importing it as:

```
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">
```

With scripts at the bottom of the `<body>`:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here are the elements I'm looking to target:

```
<div className="input-field">
  <textarea ref="ideaTextArea" className="materialize-textarea" />
  <label>Trading Ideas: with TradeDesk</label>
  <button type="submit" className="btn right blue">Share</button>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I'm adding to target the element I want to change app/assets/stylesheets directory under home.scss:

```
.input-field textarea:focus + label {
  color: #2196f3;
}

.row .input-field textarea:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2196f3;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #2196f3;
}
```

However, this is still rendering the default materialize turqoiuse colour:

[render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hwsn.png)

Would anyone know how to change the input-field text colour to #2196f3? Is my CSS attenmpt correct? How would I store materialize locally, would that be a much easier way of achieving the css changes I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found @ether 's answer to be almost the correct way of achieving this. I found that,

```
.input-field textarea:focus + label {
  color: #2196f3 !important;
}

.row .input-field textarea:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2196f3 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #2196f3 !important
}
```

also worked. It's clearly !important to overwrite the imported materialize.css file with the local values - this is good as it keeps your local css a little easier to handle only targeting specific elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you should just be able to target your `textarea`.

Check this out: **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6amho10/1/)**

```
textarea {
color:#2196f3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We all know that [!important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) is lazy and should be avoided (if possible):

> Using the !important declaration is often considered bad practice
>   because it has side effects that mess with one of CSS's core
>   mechanisms: specificity. In many cases, using it could indicate poor
>   CSS architecture.
>
> There are cases in which it's tolerable or even preferred, but make
>   sure you double check that one of those cases actually applies to your
>   situation before using it.

A better solution starts by understanding how [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) builds it's stylesheet, and once you do, create a custom build using [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) that is specific to each project so that the default stylesheet you are referencing contains your preferred colours. No need to over-write.

Download the [sass version](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/releases/download/1.0.0/materialize-src-v1.0.0.zip) will give you compete control over what components you want to include, and what properties they should have by default. Inside the sass folder you'll find _variables.scss, and this is where the default properties for the framework live. It's as easy as changing these variables and then re-compiling materialize.scss.

Inside _input-fields.scss, we can see a variable being referenced called $input-focus-color on lines 54-58:

```
// Focused input style
  &:focus:not([readonly]) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $input-focus-color;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 $input-focus-color;
  }
```

Back to variables.scss, section 10 (Forms), on line 172 we see $input-focus-color is referencing another color, $secondary-color:

```
$input-focus-color: $secondary-color !default;
```

Right at the start of variables.scss the theme colors are laid out, and pretty much everything other element color is derived from these rules:

```
// 1. Colors
// ==========================================================================

$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;

$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;
$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;
```

So, in short, changing $secondary-color would get the change you are looking for - but it will also change all other references to it. To target the textarea focus specifically, you can change the value saved to $input-focus-color.